# Playing incoming RTP video stream with gstreamer

Tags: c, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I have found a working gst-launch-based examples for sending and recieving video stream through RTP. I have rewritten them to C. Sender works fine, but reciever doesn't. I have 2 computers, A and B. When streaming B->A, it works fine, but when A->B, B is not showing the stream. The stream is coming to B (checked with wireshark). Can you take a look at the code, and see if there is any bug I haven't found?

Here's gst-launch app:

```
VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H263-1998"
gst-launch-0.10 -v gstrtpbin name=rtpbin latency=100 \
    udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS port=5000 \
    ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. \
    ! rtph263pdepay \
    ! ffdec_h263 \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace \
    ! autovideosink
    udpsrc port=5001 \
    ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 \
    ! udpsink host=$1 port=5005 sync=false async=false
```

The corresponding C code is on [1], as it's quite long.

[1] http://pastebin.com/54eHvZWH

Answer (score 0):

You are not connecting to the request-pt-map signal in rtpbin, but instead setting the caps on the udpsrc. The general idea is that rtpbin tells you that "hey, I got a new payloadnumber coming in, what is the caps I should assign to this?". Then you provide the caps (minus the payloadnumber) that you now set directly on the udpsrc. I am not sure if this will help, but that is the way you should be doing it. Running the receiver with GST_DEBUG=*rtp*:5 could maybe also provide some clues.